# What is the most efficient method to assign an X and Y header for a list of the following nature?

Tags: web-applications, python-2.7, web-scraping

The following is the data that I am trying to process. It's a list which I want to break down further for easier referencing and processing.

I will like to add an X and Y header so that I can call for its value easily by invoking list['X']['Y']. Can this be done in Python?

```
['0.0740,0.0730,0.0720,0.0300,0.0290,0.0240,0.0210,0.0200', '0.0200,0.0200,0.0150', '0.0260,0.0260,0.0200,0.0200,0.0200,0.0150', '0.0210,0.0210,0.0200,0.0170', '0.0770,0.0760,0.0740,0.0550,0.0450,0.0210', '0.0530,0.0520,0.0510,0.0230,0.0220', '0.0160,0.0160']
```

Will appreciate if someone can show me how to do it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm sorry, but I find it very hard to figure out what you are asking here. It would help if you included some code to show what you have tried, it'll make it much easier for us to help you. Perhaps you could also take a look at http://whathaveyoutried.com for a great article on how to ask good questions?

Comment: Martijn, thanks! Let me give you an example, '0.0740,0.0730,0.0720,0.0300,0.0290,0.0240,0.0210,0.0200' are the prices that individuals paid in the past for item X. I am trying to create an xy array in python where x is the item and y is the price. As you can see, there are 7 group of prices in the list. So there are 7 items but the history of prices for each item varies. Some have more than others.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list currently contains one dimension, with comma-separated strings representing your prices.

Simply use `.split(',')` to turn those strings into lists; a list comprehension makes that a breeze:

```
splitlist = [prices.split(',') for prices in yourlist]
```

This results in a list of lists:

```
[['0.0740', '0.0730', '0.0720', '0.0300', '0.0290', '0.0240', '0.0210', '0.0200'], ['0.0200', '0.0200', '0.0150'], ['0.0260', '0.0260', '0.0200', '0.0200', '0.0200', '0.0150'], ['0.0210', '0.0210', '0.0200', '0.0170'], ['0.0770', '0.0760', '0.0740', '0.0550', '0.0450', '0.0210'], ['0.0530', '0.0520', '0.0510', '0.0230', '0.0220'], ['0.0160', '0.0160']]
```

and `splitlist[0][0]` is the string `'0.0740'`.

If you need to end up with floating point values instead of strings, simply apply `map()` on the split string:

```
splitlist = [map(float, prices.split(',')) for prices in yourlist]
```

so that each individual price is mapped to a `float()` call. Now you have:

```
[[0.073999999999999996, 0.072999999999999995, 0.071999999999999995, 0.029999999999999999, 0.029000000000000001, 0.024, 0.021000000000000001, 0.02], [0.02, 0.02, 0.014999999999999999], [0.025999999999999999, 0.025999999999999999, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.014999999999999999], [0.021000000000000001, 0.021000000000000001, 0.02, 0.017000000000000001], [0.076999999999999999, 0.075999999999999998, 0.073999999999999996, 0.055, 0.044999999999999998, 0.021000000000000001], [0.052999999999999999, 0.051999999999999998, 0.050999999999999997, 0.023, 0.021999999999999999], [0.016, 0.016]]
```

and `splitlist[0][0]` has the floating point value `0.073999999999999996`.

Comment: That's a brilliant solution. I'd love to up your rep, but unfortunately, i need 15 points before I could do so. Next time, i promise! Cheers mate.

Comment: @TingPing: No worries. Do make sure you ask clear questions if you have more!